# hg shelve equivalent of git stash drop

Tags: mercurial, shelving

I have the hg shelve (not attic) extension installed, and I want to drop a patch.  In git it would be `git stash drop`.  How do I do this using the shelve extension?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Mercurial shelve extension stores patches under .hg/shelved.  Each is a simple patch file, and the filename is the name of the patch.  So to remove a patch called 'mypatch' I can simply remove the file 'mypatch' from .hg/shelved:

`rm .hg/shelved/mypatch`

Comment: See [BennyMcBenBen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25558246/1286571) for a way to remove shelves using the hg shelve UI.

Answer (score 41):

From the [Mercurial shelve documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#shelve) (or using `hg help shelve`):

> To delete specific shelved changes, use "--delete". To delete all shelved changes, use "--cleanup".
>
> options:
>
> -d --delete              delete the named shelved change(s)

So if your patch was called `my-patch`, then you would delete it using:

```
hg shelve -d my-patch
```

Answer (score 32):

If you don't want to use shelves, you can do it the following way.

```
hg diff > mylocalchanges.txt
hg revert -a
# Do your merge here, once you are done, import back your local mods
hg import --no-commit mylocalchanges.txt
```

Comment: To avoid creation `*.orig` files use: `hg revert -aC`

Answer (score 0):

I created two shell scripts based on minaz's answer:

**hgshelve**

```
#!/bin/sh
hg diff > $1 && hg revert -a
```

**hgunshelve**

```
#!/bin/sh
hg import --no-commit $1 && trash $1
```

Put them in `~/bin`. You need `sudo apt-get install trash-cli` for the `trash` command (or modify the script to either not remove the patch file, or use `rm` if you prefer).