# What is the Mercurial(hg) equivalent of git stash?

Tags: git, mercurial

What are the equivalent commands in hg for `git stash`, `git stash apply` and `git stash pop` ?

Comment: See `shelve` — also try a general search *first*. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001059/2864740  , https://markheath.net/post/git-stash-for-mercurial-users

Comment: Note that Git's `git stash` is absurdly complicated and `hg shelve` isn't, so you might not consider these "equivalent".

Answer (score 8):

*Temporarily putting away your changes:*

**Mercurial**
`hg commit [-s]` is preferred
`hg shelve` is not recommended

**Git**
`git stash`

*Listing changes put away*

**Mercurial** `hg xl`
or `hg shelve -l`

**Git**
`git stash list`

*Viewing a put-away change*

**Mercurial**
`hg diff -c <rev>`
or `hg shelve -p <name>`

**Git**
`git stash show <name>`

*Restoring put-away changes*

**Mercurial**
`hg uncommit --no-keep`
or `hg unshelve`

**Git**
`git stash pop`

*Restoring put-away changes but keeping them in the stack*

**Mercurial**
Continue to amend or
`hg uncommit --keep` or
`hg unshelve --keep`

**Git**
`git stash apply`

Comment: I use hg shelve quite often, why do you say it is not recommended?

Comment: What version of Hg supports these commands?  I'm running 3.5.2 (on windows) & uncommit, hg xl, etc are not valid commands in that version.

Comment: Mercurial Version 5.1 on Windows. See: https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/ShelveExtension where it says, "As of Mercurial 5.1, shelve is part of Mercurial core and is enabled by default." However, there is a heading at the top of the page, which discusses using it as an extension: "This extension is distributed with Mercurial 2.8 and later. If you are using an earlier version of Mercurial, see ThirdPartyShelveExtension." That last set of keywords links here: https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/ThirdPartyShelveExtension

Answer (score 0):

I use the mq extension for this (which is not enabled by default). This extensions gives me the possibility to have a set of (not yet finished) patches, I keep on top of the "official" history.

What you would do with `git stash` is now `hg qnew »patchname« && hg qpop`, `git stash pop` now becomes `hg qpush`. The biggest directly noticeable difference is, that you have to give your patch a name in mercurial, while the git variant is happy to live anonymously.

Steve Losh did a more [in depth article](https://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/08/a-git-users-guide-to-mercurial-queues/) what this extension also can do.